# JavaScript embed contentWindow

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a Javascript `postMessage` like you can do to an iframe, but now to an embed. I have to use an embed because it is for an app which is loaded on an IOS device, and since IOS has a bug with iframe width and height I need to use an embed.

This is loaded and from inside the embed I can do a postMessage to the parent, but somehow I am not able to post to the embed. What I tried:

```
document.getElementById("embed").contentWindow.postMessage(...)
document.getElementById("embed").contentDocument.postMessage(...)
document.getElementById("embed").document.postMessage(...)
document.getElementById("embed").getSVGDocument()  // will return null
```

Current embed setup:

```
<embed src="URL" id="embed" type="text/html"></embed>
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an element by Id in JS, you have to put an Id in your element so the JS script can find it:

```
<embed id="embed" src="URL" type="text/html"></embed>
```

If you don't want to use an Id, you can use the getElementsByTagName function to get your element, like this:

```
//if you only have one element of that type
document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].doSomething();

//if you have several embed elements
var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
for(var i=0;i<embeds.lenght;i++)
{
   document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[i].doSomething();
}
```

Concerning the contentWindow property, seems like it's an iFrame property only. So you'll have to use another property or switch back to iFrame. More here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's what I am doing. But `contentWindow` is undefined. I already have the right element selected, that is not the issue.

Comment: Indeed, now your code is OK with the Id problem. I've added to my answer something about the contentWindow property which seems to be exclusive to the iFrame elements.